# Usando construtor e usando set() para mesmos atributos

Tags: java

Estou estudando JPA seguindo o exemplo do [uaiContacts](http://uaihebert.com/aplicacao-web-completa-angular-twitter-bootstrap-spring-mvc-data-e-security/).

O projeto dele está no GitHub.

Peguei o exemplo do arquivo **modelContact.java**:

A classe **Contact** está mapeada:

```
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
}
```

e ela usa um construtor.

```
public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber, String email, int id) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Ele usa `set`.

A dúvida é: Por que ele usa get e `set`? Se o construtor já seta tais valores quando definimos um objeto.

Talvez não deveria usar apenas `get`?

Observações:

Não tem herança para inicializar o construtor;
Logo não entendi o `super()`, já que não tem classe pai ou talvez alguma outra classe do projeto estenda esta classe.

Código completo da classe do model contact. model/Contact.java

```
package uaiContacts.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;

    public Contact(){

    }

    public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber, String email, int id) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
    }

public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Contact){
            Contact contact = (Contact) object;
            return contact.id == id;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Peguem, caso tenham preferência, o código no gitHub:

https://github.com/uaihebert/uaicontacts

Comment: Olá! De preferência, coloque também a classe toda de `Contact` (ou um link para ela), para podermos ver os gets e sets e opinar em cima.

Comment: @DherikEditei o post com a classe completa. Também passei o link do projeto no gitHub.

Comment: Será que o @Autowired é uma forma de erança? Por que no arquivo service/ContactService.java tem esta linha.

Comment: Realmente, na classe `Contact` há o construtor vazio, conforme antecipado na resposta. O `@Autowired` é do spring, para injeção de dependência do repository na sua classe service, não tem relação com a conversa sobre herança no JPA.

Answer (score 4):

> Por que ele usa get e set? Se o construtor já seta tais valores quando
>   definimos um objeto. [...] Talvez não deveria usar apenas get?

O `set` é para atualização da informação da entidade, uma vez que ele já usa o construtor para instanciar as informações da entidade. O `get` é para a informação ficar disponível.

De outro modo, não haveria necessidade nem do `set` nem do `get`, pois o JPA não exige nem um nem outro.

> Não tem herança para inicializar o construtor; Logo não entendi o
>   super(), já que não tem classe pai ou talvez alguma outra classe do
>   projeto estenda esta classe.

Neste caso, é desnecessário mesmo.

Lembrando que o [JPA exige sempre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034403/2387977) um construtor sem argumentos.

Comment: @Skywalker, vi no seu comentário anterior. Estou ansioso para corrigir minha resposta, mas queria saber se você tem algum link/documentação falando disto. Na prática não consigo testar agora. Eu pedi o link da classe `Contact` para o André até para ver como esta classe está.

Comment: Ele disse que não está usando herança na classe `Contact`.

Comment: Mas da forma como está falando, ainda assim eu vou precisar de um construtor (`protected`) sem argumentos. Entendi certo?

Comment: Legal, @Skywalker. Valeu a contribuição também, acabei relembrando algumas coisas do JPA graças a nossa conversa.